# Google Play Store " Your Device isn't compatible with this version"

Tags: android, google-play

I see lot of questions about this problem but no definative answer. We are app development company and recently launched 2 new apps on google play store. We tested those apps on Sony Ericsson phone OS ( 2.3.4) with below MinSDkVersion mention in Manifeast.xml file. APK is installed succesfully without any issue. We tried on another phone with OS version 2.3 but shows same problem in google store.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

- When we visit google play store today we see error "Your Device isn't compatible with this version".
- We see same message for all other apps that we have developed earlier.Same apps were installed using google play store succesfully week before. all apps are now showing same problem on google play store.

**Lot of our users are complaining that they don't see our app in play store.**

Is something changed?

Here is another intresting thing. When looked at app through Chrome browser. It says device is compatible.

When clicked on install. It starts installing and fails with error 
"Could not be downloaded due to an error ( 942 )

Comment: Please add more details and research solution you have found in the web or official sites

Comment: Issue is resolved after we did a factory reset, and doing a OS upgrade

Comment: But what mean of upgrade, It should be work in your older version too

Comment: Here is final comment on this thread. I had emailed to google about this issue what our users are facing since yesterday. I had one of my user try again today ( Without doing any update ) and she confirm that today she can see app on google play store and download succesfully. So what ever was broken on google play services is fixed today!!!

Comment: Not sure why i got so many -ve voting on this thread. This was a real problem what we faced yesterday and no definative answers found in above thread...

Comment: ,yeah Ends is good and resolved your issue, keep in mind again that If no help found from web direct ask to google without wasting time

Comment: Who is -ve voting since yesterday, Moderators please take a look and check , This is the serious problem asked

Answer (score 0):

There is chance that You have made some changes that can not work on 2.3 as you have said that It was working fine before week, It means you have made some changes that now not workling for version 2.3 
So that It shows " Your Device isn't compatible with this version"  as per official website

is there no such updates from Google

For more official details - [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: It shows compatible on google Chrome and on playstore incompatible? Seeing same problem on other apps.

Comment: Seeing same problems with other apps which were not updated recently.. Still showing as incompatible.. Also i'm not the only one facing issue.Other phones same issue!

Comment: no idea.. trying to find answer to my question

Comment: stop searching on web and ask direct to google now

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your application requires a feature that one of the devices doesn't support.

You should also check to see if you have the following declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9" />
```

You want your application to work for devices running API 9 and above (not APIs 9 through 17). The code above will ensure that your application works with all devices above API 9. Note that you generally don't want to use the `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute **(as you are currently using it)**.

## update

Try clearing data from download manager (settings-apps-all) and play store, then remove your google account, then go to play store and it will ask you to link your account after that try downloading the app. (That worked for me).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lot of users complaining about same. Here is another interesting thing. When looked at app through Chrome browser. It says device is compatible.

When clicked on install. It starts installing and fails with error "Could not be downloaded due to an error ( 942 )

Comment: Did a full factory reset on phone and tried above. Still same issue. Even tried installing Whatsapp gives same error