# App in Google Play Store (Beta-Test) says "App not compatible with your devices"

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, google-play, xamarin.android

i have written an android app with xamarin.android in visual studio and compiled a release build for android 4.1 and higher. testing directly with my devices works without problems.

after building an apk and uploading it in the play store for a beta test, it says: "app not compatible with your devices". i am pretty sure, that my test devices are not the problem. what could it be??

here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="xxx" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application android:label="alone" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

[image: screenshot of problem (in german)]

on developer interface it says 10106 supported devices:

[image]

any ideas? thanks for your help...

best regards from germany,
steven

Comment: Please refer to link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738729/google-play-store-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version . Are you getting similar message? Are you using same login on multiple devices?

Comment: yes, i am getting a similar message, but i have the same problem in chrome browser (not like in the refered question). i am the developer and tester - maybe that's the problem?? should i try with different google account??

Comment: yes. Please try that.

Comment: I saw that before when your current country is excluded from the list of countries allowed for the app to download

Comment: Did you create a Release configuration build?

Answer (score 0):

I dont use xamarin , but using studio if your gradle hava a different min sdk it will overwrite whatever os on you manifest , check your gradle file .

Comment: yes, i am using visual studio (with xamarin stuff in it), but i don't know what you mean with gradle file? i don't thik i use gradle?! can you provide some further information?! thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't have a gradle file in Xamarin Android - it's used for build/package dependencies and some other stuff. The similar setting is in your project settings where you an set the min SDK, build SDK, etc. and that will overwrite your Android manifest.